# Map vim mac key with alt

Tags: macos, vim, neovim, macvim

## What I want to do

I want to map `<S-A-j>` and `<S-A-k>` on a Mac keyboard to move selected lines up and down.
So, I map:

```
" Move selected lines
xnoremap <S-A-j> :m'>+<CR>gv=gv
xnoremap <S-A-k> :m-2<CR>gv=gv
```

But it's not working, so type the `<S-A-j>` keys in insert mode:

- For `<S-A-j>` it's writing `Í`
- For `<S-A-k>` it's writing `Ë`

So I try this :

```
xnoremap Í :m'>+<CR>gv=gv
xnoremap Ë :m-2<CR>gv=gv
```

It's perfectly working. The problem is that is not easy to read and it feels like a bug right?

## What I try

### Mappings

```
"xnoremap <S-j> <A-j> :m'>+<CR>gv=gv
"xnoremap <S-k> <A-k> :m-2<CR>gv=gv

"xnoremap <S-J> <A-J> :m'>+<CR>gv=gv
"xnoremap <S-K> <A-K> :m-2<CR>gv=gv

"xnoremap <S-j><A-j> :m'>+<CR>gv=gv
"xnoremap <S-k><A-k> :m-2<CR>gv=gv

"xnoremap <S-j> <M-j> :m'>+<CR>gv=gv
"xnoremap <S-k> <M-k> :m-2<CR>gv=gv
```

### Differents Vim

MacVim and Neovim

### Terminals

I try to run on the default terminal.

I also configure my Iterm2 terminal with pref > profile > keys -> option key=Esc+

## My environment

- Apple M1 Pro
- macOs Ventura 13.4
- Iterm2
- zsh
- level: I use Ideavim frequently on Android Studio but don't really understand Vim and how it works.

## My Solution

Remap your AZERTY input to make understand Vim what you want

```
map Í <S-A-j>
map Ë <S-A-k>
xnoremap <S-A-j> :m'>+<CR>gv=gv
xnoremap <S-A-k> :m-2<CR>gv=gv
```

It will be interesting to remap all the keys from AZERTY to QWERTY for specials key (with Alt or/and Ctrl) on a different file and then source it.
I didn't find any error at the moment, in insert mode he recognizes well the right character.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. However, please don't edit your question to include it. Instead, scroll all the way down and post it as an answer. SO [encourages self-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). You will be able to accept your own answer after 48 hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a Mac thing with international keyboards.

Vim doesn't know that you pressed `Ctrl`, `Opt`, and `j` together: all it sees is `Í`, so that's all you can use in your mapping.

Moreover, `Í` is actually produced by `Opt+j`. The `Ctrl` modifier does nothing, here.

So… what are your options?

- Use the actual character produced by the key combination:

  ```
  xnoremap Í :m'>+<CR>gv=gv
  ```

  Pros:

  - works
  - no setup necessary

  Cons:

  - not portable
  - unreadable if you don't know your keyboard layout
- Set up your terminal emulator to use "Option as Meta" (Terminal.app) or "Esc+" (iTerm.app) and use `<Esc>` in your mapping:

  ```
  xnoremap <Esc>j :m'>+<CR>gv=gv
  ```

  Pros:

  - more readable than the alternative
  - slightly more portable

  Cons:

  - makes inserting special characters harder
  - potentially breaks trivial things like leaving insert mode and moving the cursor down
  - still hides the exact keys you press
  - requires setup

Comment: When I try the "Option as Meta" or "Esc+" as you say, is not working as expected. You talk about international keyboards, that he means it's working well on US keyboards right?
So is there a way to make vim understand <A-{key}> = to {caracter on AZERTY keyboard} ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this file (for example to your USER folder) [.vimMacKeys](https://github.com/Thomas-Bagnolati/vim-config/blob/master/.vimMacKeys)

```
" keyboard remap for mac
if has('mac')                            
    source ~/.vimmackeys
endif
```

Also can add the content directly inside your `.vimrc` file of course.
Note it's done from an FR keyboard and only for letter keys.
So feel free to update it for your keyboard type.

Works for Vim & IdeaVim.